# Monoid objects constructed from duals

Tags: ct.category-theory, hopf-algebras, monoidal-categories

Let $(M,\otimes)$ be a rigid monoidal category, for which left and right duals coincide. For any  object $X \in M$, we can define a monoid structure on $X \otimes X^*$: Multiplication is defined by evaluation $ev$ as follows:
$$
id \otimes ev \otimes id: X \otimes X^* \otimes X \otimes X^* \to X \otimes X^*.
$$
The unit is just given by coevaluation in the obvious way.

Is this definition correct? I can convince myself that the unit axiom of a monoid object is true - it follows from the axioms of a dual. But I'm confused about the associativity axiom.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. Associativity is easiest to prove using string diagrams; a bicategorical version of this argument shows that an adjunction gives rise to a monad (and in particular you don't need an assumption about left vs. right duals). The monoid structure you get this way is an enriched endomorphism object of $X$ with respect to a (partial) enrichment of $M$ over itself, generalizing the familiar case of $\text{FinVect}$.

Comment: $X\otimes X^*$ is also known as the internal hom of $X$; and you can prove more generally that $\hom(Y,Z)\otimes \hom(X,Y)\to \hom(X,Z)$ is "associative" in a monoidal closed category - this has appeared somewhere on MO or MSE - more specifically here : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21382/if-tensor-has-an-adjoint-is-it-automatically-an-internal-hom  (you then need to compare your map on $X^*\otimes X$ to the one on $\hom(X,X)$)

Comment: See Lemma 4.11 and further in https://global.oup.com/academic/product/categories-for-quantum-theory-9780198739616